# Recursive From for reference on tuple Single< T >( T )?

Tags: rust

There is a trick to define recursive From for reference. Like that:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Single(i32);

impl From<i32> for Single {
    fn from(src: i32) -> Self {
        Self(src)
    }
}

impl<T> From<&T> for Single
where
    T: Clone,
    Self: From<T>,
{
    fn from(src: &T) -> Self {
        From::from((*src).clone())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Single::from(13);
    dbg!(&a);

    let a = Single::from(&13);
    dbg!(&a);

    let a = Single::from(&&13);
    dbg!(&a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=78f558dfa6c1692c62a433a6f091f125)

Problem is that trick does not work if the element of the tuple is a parameter:

```rust
struct Single< E >( E );
```

The reason is conflicting implementation. The best I've got is:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Single<E>(E);

impl<E> From<E> for Single<E> {
    fn from(src: E) -> Self {
        Self(src)
    }
}

impl<E> From<&E> for Single<E>
where
    E: Clone,
    Self: From<E>,
{
    fn from(src: &E) -> Self {
        From::from((*src).clone())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Single<i32> = Single::from(13);
    dbg!(&a);

    let a: Single<i32> = Single::from(&13);
    dbg!(&a);

    let a: Single<i32> = Single::from(&&13);
    dbg!(&a);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3606c1e791826dee465d79a2024f9b09)

The limitation of the solution is that it does not allow to get From working for deep reference. That does not work:

```rust
let a : Single< i32 > = Single::from( &&13 )
```

It is a minor limitation, but I am curious is it possible to overcome it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, Rust generic try to avoid being turing complete like C++ template. Better question is why would you want such feature ?

Comment: Basically curiosity. I am getting 2 asymmetric solutions without that.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question I asked https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Stargateur Rust generics are turing complete, but they are still better than C++ templats :) However, I don't think the orphan rules are related to that - they're there to avoid breaking changes.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman if you search for solution it's because compiler have no reason to not take `impl<E> From<E> for Single<E>` directly, since `Simple<&&i32>` match `impl<&&i32> From<&&i32> for Single<&&i32>` whereas on the first implementation there is only one possible outcome and it's `Single<i32>`, the compiler have no reason to not accept the first matching generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case it is not possible to do with single Trait.
What is possible to implement a trait for each level:

```rust
impl<E> From<&E> for Single<E>
impl<E> From<&&E> for Single<E>
impl<E> From<&&&E> for Single<E>
```

Although it's not recursive.

[Related discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/recursive-from-for-reference-on-tuple-single-t-t/76323/5) on Rust forum.